# Spring Security + AngularJS: POST request

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, cookies, spring-security

I have a web application with the back using Java Spring and the front using AngularJS.

**Spring Security Configuration (Java config)**:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("loginProcessingUrl")
                    .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/demo/**","/postTest/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCustomFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
```

**CSRF filter**:

```java
public class CsrfCustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
      Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
      String token = csrf.getToken();
      if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);
      }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

**POST request from AngularJS**:

```js
$http({method:'POST',data:"celine",url:"http://localhost:8080/postTest",cache:true})
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log("success POST");
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
          console.log("status: " + status + " statusText: " + statusText);
        });
```

**-- UPDATED --**
I can use a GET request from the front to the back, but the POST request doesn't seem to work. I get a `403 Forbidden` error on the front side (in my log: "status: 403 statusText: undefined").

For the POST request, I can correctly send a XSRF-TOKEN to Spring, but Spring returns `403 Forbidden`. So I guess that the problem is coming from my configuration of Spring Security and not from Angular.

**My headers for the POST request**:
[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: read the $http docs to see how angular handles xsrf tokens in headers

Comment: Thank you for your help. From the docs: "To take advantage of this [CSRF protection], your server needs to set a token in a JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on the first HTTP GET request." But my problem here, I suppose, is because there is no XSRF-TOKEN sent from my Spring side.

Comment: can't you just add a cookie ?

Comment: I implemented CsrfCustomFilter class to send a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN, in Java. But it is not visible in my header of the POST request. However, it is visible in the header of the GET response.

Comment: Are you using cross-domain requests? I mean, is your client application running in a different port then the server application?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that's the problem because I can do a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with cross domain requests, because AngularJS does not send the XSRF header in cross domain requests. (Search for "The header will not be set for cross-domain requests" on [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)).

Writing this `$http` interceptor

```
angular.module('appBoot')
  .factory('XSRFInterceptor', function ($cookies, $log) {

    var XSRFInterceptor = {

      request: function(config) {

        var token = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');

        if (token) {
          config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
          $log.info("X-XSRF-TOKEN: " + token);
        }

        return config;
      }
    };
    return XSRFInterceptor;
  });
```

and configuring it like this

```
angular.module('appBoot', ['ngCookies', 'ngMessages', 'ui.bootstrap', 'vcRecaptcha'])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

      $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('XSRFInterceptor');

    }]);
```

solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and notify you if it works.

Comment: I have updated my question. Now I can send a XSRF-TOKEN from Angular, but I still get "403 Forbidden" from server side.

Comment: Hope your csrfTokenRepository() sets the name of the header to `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. I have a working example at https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon. See if the  LemonSecurityConfig.java and other files there are of any help.

Comment: Yes, the csrfTokenRepository() sets the name of the header to X-XSRF-TOKEN. Thank you, I'll try your github example..